# *** recipe commences before first target. Stop

Tags: makefile

I just download the android open source project and tried to build it with make the I receive the message:

```
build/core/prebuilt.mk:91: *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.
```

Here is the corresponding make file snippet (The first line here being line number 89):

```
ifneq ($(prebuilt_module_is_a_library),)
  ifneq ($(LOCAL_IS_HOST_MODULE),)
    $(transform-host-ranlib-copy-hack)
  else
    $(transform-ranlib-copy-hack)
  endif
endif
```

I am not sure what's wrong with this make file? The preceding white space on line 91 is a tab.

Comment: The `TAB` means that Make interprets line 91 as a command, which should be part of a rule. The snippet is enough to go on; if it is part of a rule, Make is somehow failing to parse the first line of the rule correctly, and if it is *not* part of a rule, line 91 should not be a command and should not begin with a `TAB`.

Comment: The question is what comes BEFORE this in the makefile?  It seems likely that the variable `transform-host-ranlib-copy-hack` is supposed to be part of a recipe, so having it be preceded by a TAB is correct.  The problem is that make doesn't think you're in a recipe context, which means that something before the `ifeq` you've shown is not right.  My suspicion is that the version of make you have is not compatible with the version used by the author of the open source project and whatever comes before the `ifeq` is not portable between them.

Comment: @MadScientist It seems to be the case. It needs make version 3.8.1 and my make version is 4.0. I thought it is backward compatible.

Comment: There is no version 3.8.1.  I guess you mean 3.81.  They are mostly backward-compatible but there are incompatible changes over time (3.81 was released in 2006).  The differences are usually easy to deal with and often the older syntax was not intended to be valid but wasn't checked properly.  Without seeing the lines before the `ifeq` that's about all I can say.  See http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/NEWS for info on changes to each version of make.

Answer (score 21):

Make is very touchy about spaces and tabs, it treats indented lines as commands, so you need to remove them. E.g. it should be:

```
ifneq ($(prebuilt_module_is_a_library),)
ifneq ($(LOCAL_IS_HOST_MODULE),)
$(transform-host-ranlib-copy-hack)
else
$(transform-ranlib-copy-hack)
endif
endif
```

Comment: You still do indentation for readability using spaces, just not tabs

Comment: @CallumMacDonald True, though I hate that I have to break my no-mixing-tabs-and-spaces-for-indentation rule just for Make. >8^(

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error message because of tabs after line continuation:

```
SOURCES := a.cpp \
b.cpp \<tab><tab>
c.cpp \
d.cpp
```

Answer (score 3):

I build **AOSP** 2.3.1 on **Ubuntu 16**, then got the same error as you have.
Then I changed the **make version** from **v4.1** to **v3.81**, notice that **v3.82** also is the wrong version. Finally I build AOSP successfully!

Comment: It's crazy that AOSP is depending on 10+ yo software:

make-3.81.tar.bz2 2006-04-01

https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/

Comment: This is still valid with current sources.